# Compare directories with ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, diff

I have a directory dirA on my laptop, and a directory dirB on a remote host to which I can `ssh`. Both directories include subdirectories.

I would like to compare the full content of the two subdirectories by using ssh. In particular, I want to know what file or subdirectory in dirA is not in dirB, and the other way around. The two directories are large enough that I do not want to transfer the full files through `ssh`, just compare their names and locations.

Do you know how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use `rsync` with the `--dry-run` option; something like:

```
rsync -ar --dry-run local-dir/ user@remote:remote-dir
```

This will output the list of files that *would have been synchronized*. So if there is no output; there is no difference.

**edit :** Two options you might consider:

- `--ignore-times` : ignore the timestamp of the local and remote files when comparing the files.
- `--size-only` : if you want to speedup the rsync command. rsync compares only the size of the files. Note that this is error prone (files with same size might differ)
- `--itemize-changes` : show the changes between files

you may take a look at [this anwser](https://serverfault.com/a/618740/218192)

Comment: You may want to turn off checking modification times etc. so that only file contents is compared (if even that!).

Comment: @SergeBallesta Does it? I thought `rsync` was smarter than that and compared checksums. If it didn't, it would not be different from a recursive `scp`...

Comment: @Kusalananda: thanks for the hint; I added some information about the rsync options he might consider...

Comment: This does not work: I created a directory test on my laptop 
`XXX$ ls /Users/XXX/Desktop/test/
1.dat 2.dat` 
and one on the remote host 
`XXX% ls /n/homeserver2/user2a/XXX/test
1.dat` then I run `rsync -ar --dry-run /Users/XXX/Desktop/test/ XXX@XXX.XXX.XXX:/n/homeserver2/user2a/XXX/test` and I get no output, while there should be a difference between the two directories.

Comment: you are right; I added the "--itemize-changes" option to my answer. Check also the related answer.

Comment: This works, thank you. I get the following output `.d..tp... ./
<f..tp... 1.dat
<f+++++++ 2.dat`, may you please explain to me what `<f+++++++ 2.dat` means?

Comment: http://andreafrancia.it/2010/03/understanding-the-output-of-rsync-itemize-changes.html